# Passing a two dimensional array to function in GTK in C

Tags: c, arrays, gtk, arguments

I tried passing a two-dimensional array as argument to a function in GTK, without success. How can I edit the order of the buttons in the array?

```
GtkWidget *botones[4][4];
```

...

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(botones[0][0]), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(borra), botones);
```

...

```
void borra(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer info)
 {
    GtkWidget **elementos= (GtkWidget*) info;

     ...

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`botones` is a 4*4 array of `GtkWidget *`, when you call `g_signal_connect`, you cast it to a `gpointer` which is typedef for `void *`, then in the callback function, you should cast the `gpointer` back to a pointer to an array of 4 `GtkWidget *` like this:

```
GtkWidget * (*elementos)[4] = (GtkWidget *(*)[4])info;
```

Then you can use `elementos[0][0]` to access the 2-D array.

Comment: but doing it that way I will edit just "elementos[][]" right?, the changes won't be saved in "botones[][]"

Comment: what I mean is that the array is passing as value not as reference

Comment: Not working? you mean you can't modify the global array?